# How to make one type depends on argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to make return type of function dependent on the argument type?

```
const exampleFunction<T> = (initial?: T, ...anotherArgs) => { ...Some logic }
```

In this example by default we can use T | undefined, but I need that return type of function always be T if initial data is defined and (T | undefined) if it is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make return type of function dependent on the argument type?

This question in a general sense is typically answered by [function overloads.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

In this case you could do something like:

```
function exampleFunction<T>(initial: T): T // overload 1
function exampleFunction(initial?: undefined): undefined // overload 2

// Implementation
function exampleFunction<T>(initial?: T): T | undefined {
    return initial
}

const a: { abc: number } = exampleFunction({ abc: 123 }) // use overload 1

const b: undefined = exampleFunction() // use overload 2
const c: undefined = exampleFunction(undefined) // use overload 2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgMXGnjAB4AVAPgAoYwZZ1cAuRCgSjYsQHpfEcAG7IATrjjoAJogCMAWABQoSLAQoMOfEVWk6DJrgD8bcFOTB6yKV0RmLVmf0EjxkmQCYlS5wEktyJjIYFDoamBKKiTqaFh4hMThlLT0jDDMJuy2PAA+dmDmlmDWiADeSoiViKLIUCCiSKmGSgC+3ooQCADOUIjobKV9AEYQbGAgmENiiC2IALwacdqJeoPoI2yyHgDMMxx8AiBdyC5iEtJy7Z1gPYhDpgUOxTILsQE60WA0+85HJ8JndyILwdbq9Ub5QqOeaLd4rBA0exFaw-Q7HU5uC4eIA)

---

However, reading your question more carefully...

> always be T if initial data is defined and (T | undefined) if it is undefined

You can change the second overload to:

```
function exampleFunction<T>(initial?: undefined): T | undefined // overload 2
```

But that will require a manual type for `T` since none can be inferred.

```
const b: { def: string } | undefined = exampleFunction<{ def: string }>() // use overload 2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=92&pln=11&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgMXGnjAB4AVAPgAoYwZZ1cAuRCgSjYsQHpfEcAG7IATrjjoAJogCMAWABQoSLAQoMOfEVWlKteoxjMA-G3BTkwesild2iAD6ILVmzP6CR4yTIBMSkqeAJJayJjIYFDoamBKKiTqaFh4hMSx+nQMTLhm7PY8zq7WYLaIAN5KiNWIoshQIKJIhjlKAL6BihAIAM5QiOhs5QMARhBsYCCYI2KIbYgAvBop2umkNMPoY2yyfgDMcxx8AiA9yF5iEtJynd1gfYgjQ4iWwGx9ovQA5nNOLmCvdyLZZhHSJcjDV7vKCfMA-Nq0I6eU7nYSXXyIPxAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function which simply extracts the first element type from rest parameters.

- If no arguments are provided, the return type will be `undefined` because the first argument's type is (implicitly) `undefined`
- If the first argument is `T | undefined`, so will be the return type
- If the first argument type is `T`, so will be the return type

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAngBwKYHlgDEYBOAzlAIIEDmIAthmFIgDzkVGIYAeUdAJmwRgCGPBABsUiQWBQBtALoA+ABQA6NYMpEAXIhZEAlDr0yADHMQBvAFCJEEBCUQzghEuYC8kzQG4biAPT+iGoqfgJQIARILsRQvgC+Vlb2YI4CRCCiUACMiJ6omDj4sSw0dFBK+t4BQeA8GC5gGDzJDgzpmVAATHnI6Nh4rmSUZfRKAORwANbjADSI41JwUAAWGATjVTWIJAQwYBStqe0YGVkAzL0FA8UkpbRjITKTM-OLYMtrG+aCbCkkW0CiAARNNgUc0qdOgAWK79IpDe7lJQWRDUIgUHTjNaiURwRAAdzgBFEPHGiHi82ewDgcDmCwARhpxnJAUFUejMTsoHsDhSkqIMAwAG6CUQgDA6Xb7CiIAA+iDqDX2zV8-xOZygAFY4YVBiURg8KqLxRg2dzebKFUrGs0rEA)

```ts
function typeOfFirstArgument <Args extends readonly any[]>(...args: Args): Args[0] {
  const [first] = args;
  // ...
  return first;
}

const result1 = typeOfFirstArgument(); // undefined
const result2 = typeOfFirstArgument('ok', 'another'); // string
const result3 = typeOfFirstArgument(...['ok', 'another'] as const); // "ok"
const result4 = typeOfFirstArgument({ msg: 'hello world' }, ['foo', 'bar']); // { msg: string }

let value: string | undefined;
const result5 = typeOfFirstArgument(value); // string | undefined
```